# custom round logic off in SQL

Tags: oracle

Iwant to round of the value upto 2 decimal point when third decimal digit is greater then 5:

```
 39.956 should be round off to 39.96,
 35.665 should be round off to 35.66 ,
 39.997 should be round off to 40.00 ,
 56.684 should be round off to 56.68.
```

I am trying to do below

```
SELECT   CAST(FLOOR(VALUE) AS VARCHAR2(30))
   + CASE
         WHEN CAST(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, '.')), 4) AS INT) > 5
         THEN
             CONCAT(
                    '.',
                    (  SUBSTR(
                              SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, '.')),
                              2,
                              2
                             )
                     + 1)
                   )
         ELSE
             CONCAT(
                    '.',
                    SUBSTR(
                           SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, '.')),
                           2,
                           2
                          )
                   )
     END
FROM DUAL;
```

but for the border cases, for example 39.897 and 39.997 it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you simply need this:

```
SQL> with test(num) as (
  2      select 39.956 from dual union all
  3      select 35.665 from dual union all
  4      select 39.997 from dual union all
  5      select 56.684 from dual
  6  )
  7  select num, round(num -0.001, 2)
  8  from test;

       NUM ROUND(NUM-0.001,2)
---------- ------------------
    39,956              39,96
    35,665              35,66
    39,997                 40
    56,684              56,68
```

Comment: for  SELECT ROUND(39.995,2) FROM dual;  it is giving 40, but i want it to be 39.99 only , as i asked in the question when third decimal digit is greater than 5 (i.e from 6) then only i want to incremant the 2nd decimal digit. it little different from the original round off logic ROUND(NUM,2) ,

Comment: @Aleksej I think you should put the `0 -.001` inside the `round` call rather than in the data to better reflect what needs to be done.

Comment: @MinkuJha change it to `round(39.995-001, 2)` i.e. `round(value-001,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Aleksej's solution will work fine and is probably the most efficient **if** it is known beforehand that the input numbers have at most three decimal places.

The problem can be generalized though, like so: round 38.445 down to 38.44; however, round 38.44503 to 38.45. (That is, if there are non-zero digits after the "5" in the third decimal position, then round up.)

Something like the query below can be used in the general case. The only time the result is different from "usual" rounding is when the input number has exactly three non-zero decimal places, and the third decimal place is 5. This is exactly how the solution reads.

```
with inp (n) as (select 38.445 from dual union all select 38.44503 from dual)
select n,
       round(n,2) - case when n = round(n, 3) and mod(1000*n, 10) = 5 
                         then 0.01 
                         else 0    end  as custom_rounded
from   inp;



         N CUSTOM_ROUNDED
---------- --------------
    38.445          38.44
  38.44503          38.45
```

Comment: As per my Requirment Above logic is working fine , when 3 rd decimal digit is greater then 5 then only it needs to be incremented. 38.44503 should be round off to  38.44 .

Comment: Interesting but completely illogical. There can be different choices for rounding 0.5 to an integer value, to either 0 or 1, and both are equally logical, valid and legitimate. There is no possible logical reason to want to round 0.59 as integer to 0 instead of 1. In any case, I offered this solution not necessarily for your problem, but for possible future readers who would need a more general solution to what I think is the more logical requirement.